# read input from text file for data in google chart api

Tags: javascript, jsp, google-visualization

I am using the Google Chart API to implement a pie chart.The example on their website: https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#pie_chart uses static values to make the chart.

What if I want the data to be read from a text file? How do I go about doing it?